# docker repository in artifactory-registry 4.7

Tags: nginx, vagrant, artifactory, docker-registry

I am trying out the registry version of artifactory that supports the docker repositories. For this I created a vagrant vm on my mac and ran the artifactory registry docker image by forwarding ports 8081, 443.

Here is the vagrant file

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provision "docker"

  config.vm.hostname = "docker"
  config.vm.box = "phusion/ubuntu-14.04-amd64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8081, host: 8081
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 443


  # Sync your project in the /vagrant directory inside the VM
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
end
```

I am able to access the artifactory UI at http://localhost:8081
Based on the documentation I am trying to access the virtual docker repository at

```
docker push art.local:6555/ubuntu
```

I get a host not found error

```
Get https://art.local:6555/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup art.local: no such host
```

Here is the nginx config that shipped with the image

```
## add ssl entries when https has been set in config
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/demo.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/demo.key;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
## server configuration
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80 ;

    server_name art.local;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/art.local-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/art.local-error.log;
    rewrite ^/$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/artifactory/?(/webapp)?$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    location /artifactory/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

## server configuration
server {
    listen 6555 ssl;


    server_name art.local;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/art.local-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/art.local-error.log;
    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/docker-virtual/$1/$2;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    location /artifactory/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Nt sure if this is the correct usage of the trial repos

Comment: Did you create a `docker-virtual` repository in Artifactory?

Comment: yes it was already created as a part of the docker image